# Web Scraping Easy Apply Button From LinkedIn URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, excel-formula, linkedin-api, screen-scraping

I am looking for a tool or a script that will scrape a Linkedin URL job posting in Column D and Return a result of Easy Apply or Apply in Column E. I have a list of 1,000+ links and I want to know which URLS have the Easy Apply button.

I have tried using a python script but it is requiring me to get a Google API credential.

I have done some research and found that if a URL contains the text "/jobs/view/" followed by a series of numbers, followed by the text "?eBP=JOB_POSTING" it is an "Easy Apply" job posting. This is not the case after spot checking a hundred URL's.

All the jobs in the google sheets have been applied to by my case load and I need to determine the percentage of postings that were Easy Applies.

If anyone has any advise on a best way to determine if a job posting is an Easy Apply or just a normal Apply that would be a huge help.

Here is the google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gG0VYBm5tlCAnDrGwFqdsjxfK6qiEzEFGb82O8nMZXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Solely relying on the HTML content of those links is also unreliable. I did some checks and found inaccurate results by using Apps Script and scraping each HTML content, looking for a class named `artdeco-button__text` with text content `Easy Apply`. Have you also checked the LinkedIn API documentation?